# Yii - trouble at the beginning

Tags: yii, controller, localhost, http-status-code-404

What i did:

1. Instaled XAMPP (default settings)
2. Downloaded and instaled newest version of Yii (c:\xampp\htdocs\yii)
3. Made PATH (;c:\xampp\php)
4. I did everything what i should in CMD, after that localhost/yii/test is working but when i make new controller and i try go to site localhost/yii/test/bazadanych, then i have 404 error.

---

(c:\xampp\htdocs\yii\test\protected\controllers\BazadanychController.php)

```
<?php
    class BazadanychController extends CController
    {
        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $Polaczenie = Yii::app()->db;
            $Zapytanie = $Polaczenie->createCommand('CELECT * FROM osoby');
            $DaneZBazy = $Zapytanie->query();
            while(($Rekord=$DaneZBazy->read())!==false)
            {
                echo $Rekord['imie'].'<br>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Where did i mistake? I read polish book "yiiframework"  (Author: Łukasz Sosna, printed this year) and i made step by step so i don't know what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Did the Yii app work ok before you added your controller?

Comment: Yes, i created app by command **yiic webapp test** and it was working when i go to _localhost/yii/test_ and i still see yii webapplication homepage on this adress, but when i create new controller and when i try to call then i see 404.

before i made **BazadanychController** i made **StronaController** whith simply class

`class StronaController extends CController
{
public function actionIndex()
{
echo 'simply text';
}
}`

but adress _yii/test/strona_ shows 404

Comment: have you included the accesRules()http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth#access-control-filter

Comment: Stupid me... Problem solved but i forgot .htaccess